# Custom logout url and redirection in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, logout

In Woocommerce, I am using below code customizing some redirections. Everything is working fine.

I have jus a problem with **logout that is not working** when using `?customer-logout=true` in the menu, because it's redirected to `/dashboard/` page.

This is my code for redirection:

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'redirect_to_my_account_dashboard' );
function redirect_to_my_account_dashboard( $wp ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $allowed_endpoints = [ 'downloads', 'orders', 'edit-account', 'lost-password', 'reset-password', 'payment-methods', 'view-order', 'customer-logout' ];
        if (
            preg_match( '%^account(?:/([^/]+)|)/?$%', $wp->request, $m ) &&
            ( empty( $m[1] ) || ! in_array( $m[1], $allowed_endpoints ) )
        ) {
            wp_redirect( '../dashboard/' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code and I don't get any problem to logout when using the logout menu item.

Comment: what is logout menu url? is that ?customer-logout=true ? I am still unable to logout

Comment: Yes, Its working fine, If i use menu item like example.com/?customer-logout=true, Its not working if i use like example.com/account/?customer-logout=true

Comment: Its working fie, actually one of plugin causing issue.